# Ruby extend & include tracing code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, include, extend

I'm confused about using "include" vs "extend, after searching for hours all I got is that module methods used with instance of the class including the module, and module methods used with the class itself when the class extending the module of those methods.

but this didn't help me to figure out, why this code give error when commenting the extend module line in "#extend Inventoryable"
while work when uncomment it, here's the code

```
module Inventoryable

    def create(attributes)
      object = new(attributes)
      instances.push(object)
      return object
    end

    def instances
      @instances ||= []
    end

  def stock_count
    @stock_count ||= 0
  end

  def stock_count=(number)
    @stock_count = number
  end

  def in_stock?
    stock_count > 0
  end
end

class Shirt
  #extend Inventoryable
  include Inventoryable
  attr_accessor :attributes

  def initialize(attributes)
    @attributes = attributes
  end
end

 shirt1 = Shirt.create(name: "MTF", size: "L")
 shirt2 = Shirt.create(name: "MTF", size: "M")
 puts Shirt.instances.inspect
```

the output is

```
store2.rb:52:in `<main>': undefined method `create' for Shirt:Class (NoMethodError)
```

while when uncomment the "extend Inventoryable" to make the code work:

```
module Inventoryable

    def create(attributes)
      object = new(attributes)
      instances.push(object)
      return object
    end

    def instances
      @instances ||= []
    end

  def stock_count
    @stock_count ||= 0
  end

  def stock_count=(number)
    @stock_count = number
  end

  def in_stock?
    stock_count > 0
  end
end

class Shirt
  extend Inventoryable
  include Inventoryable
  attr_accessor :attributes

  def initialize(attributes)
    @attributes = attributes
  end
end

 shirt1 = Shirt.create(name: "MTF", size: "L")
 shirt2 = Shirt.create(name: "MTF", size: "M")
 puts Shirt.instances.inspect
```

makes the code work and output the following

```
[#<Shirt:0x0055792cb93890 @attributes={:name=>"MTF", :size=>"L"}>, #<Shirt:0x0055792cb937a0 @attributes={:name=>"MTF", :size=>"M"}>]
```

it's kinda confusing, but all I need to know, is why I need to extend the module in order to avoid the error ?, and how to edit this code to make it work without the extend method ? , what's left in the code that still depends on the extend ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `extend` a module, the methods in that module become "class methods"**. So, when you `extend Inventoryable`, `create` becomes available as a method on the `Shirt` class.

When you `include` a module, the methods in that module become "instance methods"**. So, when you `include Inventoryable`, `create` is not available on the `Shirt` class (but *is* available on an instance of `Shirt`).

To make `create` available on the `Shirt` class when using `include`, you can use the `included` hook. That might look something like:

```
module Inventoryable
  module ClassMethods

    def create
      puts "create!"
    end

  end

  module InstanceMethods

  end

  def self.included(receiver)
    receiver.extend ClassMethods
    receiver.include InstanceMethods
  end
end
```

Then if you do:

```
class Shirt
  include Invetoryable
end
```

You can do:

```
> Shirt.create
create!
 => nil
```

** The ruby purists in the crowd will correctly point out that, in ruby, everything is an instance method and that there are no class methods. That is formally 100% correct, but we'll use the colloquial meaning of `class` and `instance` methods here.

Comment: Glad it worked. You'll be metaprogramming like a mad dog in no time.

Comment: I want to state that I am one of those Ruby Purists who likes to point out that there is no such thing as a class method in Ruby. I am perfectly fine, though, with using the term *class method* colloquially, **as long as it is fully understood by all parties that it is a colloquial usage**. In other words, if you *know* that there is no such thing as a class method and that the term "class method" is just short for "instance method of the singleton class of an object that is an instance of `Class`", then there is no problem. But otherwise, I have only seen it obstruct understanding.

Comment: Ruby really is much simpler than many people make it sound like, and introducing artificial distinctions where there are none is one of the reasons for that, I believe.

Comment: Nice to see you again, Jörg W Mittag!

Answer (score 1):

When you extend a module in a class, you get the module's methods exposed as class methods but if you include the module then you get the module's method as instance methods, in your example for you to be able to call `create` method of `Inventoryable` class you need to invoke it using an instance of `Shirt` class (if you include the module)

```
shirt1 = Shirt.new(attributes).create(attributes)
```

Without more info I can't tell what you are trying to do but you need to redesign the `initialize` and `create` methods to decide where or what to do in those methods.

I'll try to explain it using a simple example

```
module A
  def test
    puts "ok"
  end
end

class B
  include A
end

class C
  extend A
end

puts C.test # here you invoke the method against the class itself
puts B.new.test #here you create an instance to do it
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your help, after editing the code to be like this...

 `shirt1 = Shirt.new(name: "MTF", size: "L").create(name: "MTF", size: "L")
 shirt2 = Shirt.new(name: "MTF", size: "M").create(name: "MTF", size: "M")
 puts Shirt.instances.inspect`                                                                                                  I still get error which is "store2.rb:4:in `create': undefined method `new' for #<Shirt:0x00561581043750 @attributes={:name=>"MTF", :size=>"L"}> (NoMethodError)   
        from store2.rb:36:in `<main>'  "

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, it's really simple:

- `C.include(M)` makes the current superclass of `C` the superclass of `M` and `M` the superclass of `C`. In other words, it inserts `M` into `C`'s ancestry chain.
- `obj.extend(M)` is (roughly) the same as `obj.singleton_class.include(M)`.